# Go Varint Returns Half of Expected Value

Tags: go

Why is the output of this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/binary"
)

func main() {
    var myByte byte = 18
    array := []byte{myByte}
    val, n := binary.Varint(array)
    fmt.Printf("value: %d, num bytes: %d\n", val, n)
}
```

`value: 9, num bytes: 1` instead of `value: 18, num bytes: 1`

It probably has something to do with two's complement, but I'm not seeing how.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** Use the `Uvarint` method to properly decode an *unsigned* byte .. which is what a `byte` is by default.

The byte is stored unsigned (as a byte is unsigned by default - it is an alias for `uint8` .. in most languages).

When you're decoding the number, you're calling `binary.Varint` .. which decodes a signed number. This results in the number being incorrect because of the sign bit.

Using `binary.Uvarint` .. that is, decode an unsigned number, you get the correct result:

```
val, n := binary.Uvarint(array) // val = 18, n = 1
```

#### Expanded example:

Lets take a look at your number - 18. In binary, it is this:

```
00010010
```

The `binary.Varint` function is below:

```
func Varint(buf []byte) (int64, int) {
    ux, n := Uvarint(buf) // ok to continue in presence of error
    x := int64(ux >> 1)
    if ux&1 != 0 {
        x = ^x
    }
    return x, n
}
```

Basically, it will first go and get the unsigned value of what you've provided: `18`.

It will then shift all of the bytes across by 1. This results in:

```
00001001
```

That is the binary representation of `9`. Notice the sign bit is still 0 - which means a positive number. It then checks whether to invert the result by bitwise AND'ing the original value (`18`) with `1`. It does this because, it is operating with a "I know this number is signed" context - that's why the function exists:

```
00010010
00000001
--------
00000000
     = 0
```

At that point, zero does equal zero - so the method returns `x` - which is 9.

#### Lets try with 1

Using 1 as the input:

```
00000001
```

Shift it right:

```
00000000
```

AND *the original number (1)* with 1:

```
00000001
00000001
--------
     = 1
```

At this point, the result doesn't equal zero.. so the result is inverted:

```
11111111
```

This is the signed representation of `-1` (notice the sign bit is now 1 .. indicating a negative number).

Comment: Ok, but why does my input of 18 produce 9?  18 = 00010010

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check this modified version: http://play.golang.org/p/AyP2a4gue8

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        var myByte byte = byte(i)
        array := []byte{myByte}
        val, n := binary.Varint(array)
        fmt.Printf("int %d value: %d, num bytes: %d\n", i, val, n)

    }    
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
int 0 value: 0, num bytes: 1
int 1 value: -1, num bytes: 1
int 2 value: 1, num bytes: 1
int 3 value: -2, num bytes: 1
int 4 value: 2, num bytes: 1
int 5 value: -3, num bytes: 1
int 6 value: 3, num bytes: 1
int 7 value: -4, num bytes: 1
int 8 value: 4, num bytes: 1
int 9 value: -5, num bytes: 1
int 10 value: 5, num bytes: 1
int 11 value: -6, num bytes: 1
int 12 value: 6, num bytes: 1
int 13 value: -7, num bytes: 1
int 14 value: 7, num bytes: 1
int 15 value: -8, num bytes: 1
int 16 value: 8, num bytes: 1
int 17 value: -9, num bytes: 1
int 18 value: 9, num bytes: 1
```

You can see "zig-zagging" between the negatives and positives.  This is because, according to the [documented binary format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?csw=1#types), varints use "zig-zag" encoding so that values of small absolute value are encoded with small values.

Comment: Ok, so why does 2 produce 1, and 1 produce -1?